# Errors on tutorial Authorize specific nodes

Tags: substrate-tutorial, pallet-node-authorization, cargo-check

I am following the tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/

Once I reach the point

*5. Check that the new dependencies resolve correctly by running the following command:*

```
cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release
```

I get the following error:

```
username-MacBook-Pro runtime % cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release
warning: virtual workspace defaulting to `resolver = "1"` despite one or more workspace members being on edition 2021 which implies `resolver = "2"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: for more details see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#resolver-versions
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git`
error: failed to get `pallet-node-authorization` as a dependency of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/username/Desktop/Dev/substrate_tutorials/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `pallet-node-authorization`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0

Caused by:
  failed to find branch `polkadot-v1.0.0`

Caused by:
  cannot locate remote-tracking branch 'origin/polkadot-v1.0.0'; class=Reference (4); code=NotFound (-3)
```

Please have a look at the Cargo.toml below

```
[package]
name = "node-template-runtime"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "A fresh FRAME-based Substrate node, ready for hacking."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "MIT-0"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.6.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }

pallet-aura = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-balances = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-sudo = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-try-runtime = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-timestamp = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-transaction-payment = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-executive = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-block-builder = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-consensus-aura = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-consensus-grandpa = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-core = { version = "21.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-inherents = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-offchain = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-runtime = { version = "24.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-session = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-std = { version = "8.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-transaction-pool = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
sp-version = { version = "22.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }


# Used for the node template's RPCs
frame-system-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

# Used for runtime benchmarking
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
frame-system-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

# Local Dependencies
pallet-template = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../pallets/template" }

[build-dependencies]
substrate-wasm-builder = { version = "5.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "frame-try-runtime?/std",
    "frame-system-benchmarking?/std",
    "frame-benchmarking?/std",
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-executive/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-try-runtime/std",
    "pallet-aura/std",
    "pallet-balances/std",
    "pallet-grandpa/std",
    "pallet-sudo/std",
    "pallet-template/std",
    "pallet-timestamp/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment-rpc-runtime-api/std",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/std",
    "sp-api/std",
    "sp-block-builder/std",
    "sp-consensus-aura/std",
    "sp-consensus-grandpa/std",
    "sp-core/std",
    "sp-inherents/std",
    "sp-offchain/std",
    "sp-runtime/std",
    "sp-session/std",
    "sp-std/std",
    "sp-transaction-pool/std",
    "sp-version/std",
    "substrate-wasm-builder",
    "pallet-node-authorization/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-support/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    "frame-system/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-balances/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-grandpa/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-sudo/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-template/runtime-benchmarks",
    "pallet-timestamp/runtime-benchmarks",
    "sp-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
]
try-runtime = [
    "frame-try-runtime/try-runtime",
    "frame-executive/try-runtime",
    "frame-system/try-runtime",
    "frame-support/try-runtime",
    "pallet-aura/try-runtime",
    "pallet-balances/try-runtime",
    "pallet-grandpa/try-runtime",
    "pallet-sudo/try-runtime",
    "pallet-template/try-runtime",
    "pallet-timestamp/try-runtime",
    "pallet-transaction-payment/try-runtime",
]
```

As per the tutorial my only additions are

```
pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }
```

and

```
"pallet-node-authorization/std",
```

in features

Note: If I replace this with

```
pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev" }
```

errors are not showing up any more but in the next step of the tutorial where lib.rs is amended the same cargo check command returns dozens of errors.

Q1: Any suggestions please?

Q2: Are there any polkadot repos that host the solved tutorials so I can always double check my progress (e.g. Cargo.toml, lib.rs) versus a working repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

`pallet-node-authorization = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }`

Because your project imported version `polkadot-v1.0.0` from `substrate` repository, not from `polkadot-sdk`
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v1.0.0

**Ensure that your dependencies project are in the same branch and repository**